# Nginx location without trailing slash works only with trailing slash

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, reverse-proxy, apache-zeppelin

I have a strange problem with using a nginx as a reverse proxy for my Zeppelin instance. I will try to describe the problem below.

I am using an EC2 instance as the reverse proxy to access the Zeppelin instance. Just a note in front of that is an AWS ALB sitting as "forward proxy", this way I can use a friendly URL's for exposing the UI's. The [path based routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#path-conditions) on the AWS ALB is configured correctly.

1. The request is coming to AWS ALB with domain **subdomain.domain.com/ds** where I am using a path based routing to match all requests that are hitting the /ds as a path to my target group.
2. The incoming request is then passed to Nginx instance, which is working well. The problem is that if I am using a URL without trailing slash, the Nginx simply timeouts.

The configuration is below:

```
# Zeppelin
server {
    listen 541;
    location /ds {
        rewrite ^/ds/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10:8890/;
        proxy_redirect http://10.10.10.10:8890/ $scheme://$host/ds;
    }
    location /ds/ws {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10:8890/ws;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
        proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }
}
```

Also, bellow is the most simple example that I am using for RStudio.

```
server {
    listen 542;


    location /ds {
      rewrite ^/ds/(.*)$ /$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10:8787;
      proxy_redirect http://10.10.10.10:8787/ $scheme://$host/ds/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_read_timeout 20d;
    }
}
```

In case that trailing slash is not provided, I am getting

```
/ds not found
```

Comment: So would you want `subdomain.domain.com/zeppelin/ds` to redirect to `subdomain.domain.com/zeppelin`? The problem may be in your rewrite rule. Try adding a rule like `rewrite ^/ds / break;`

Comment: @BenWhaley See edit. subdomain.domain.com/ds is needed to be redirected. However, when adding above rule causes too many redirects.

Comment: It might be that you are not rewriting `/ds` to `/` when passing the URI upstream. Try: `rewrite ^/ds/?(.*)$ /$1 break;`

Comment: @RichardSmith You were correct. I would appreciate if you could write an answer so I can accept it. Just a short notice, without that, the redirect is adding a port after some time (542) which timeouts because my ALB is not listening on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `location` block:

```
location /ds {
    rewrite ^/ds/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    ...  
    proxy_pass ...
}
```

URIs which begin with `/ds/` will match the regular expression and be rewritten without the initial `/ds`. However, the URI `/ds` does not match the regular expression and will be passed to the upstream application as `/ds`.

There are a number of ways to fix the problem, but the simplest solution is to make the second `/` in the regular expression optional by adding a `?` operator.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/ds/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
```